# transactional fixtures in gem development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions, rspec, rubygems

Can't I use transactional fixtures in gem (not Rails) development?

I added this to my spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.filter_run :focus => true
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
  config.filter_run_excluding :exclude => true

  config.mock_with :rspec

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
end
```

But I get:

```
undefined method `use_transactional_fixtures=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0xb7313ca8> (NoMethodError)
```

Do I really have to take care of the database cleanup myself (maybe with another plugin), or could I simply "require" something to make transactional fixtures work?

### Update

Here are my current requires:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
require 'logger'
require 'active_record'
require 'rspec'
require 'active_support'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`use_transactional_fixtures` RSpec support is defined in `rspec-rails`. You need to include that Gem or reproduce its functionalities in order to use it.

See https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/6fa688fa38be8e5fc17beb4ab82e8c3981a9b8fd/lib/rspec/rails/fixture_support.rb#L11-16

Comment: Thanks, Simone. I just pondered about why it is in rspec-rails and not in the core. I guess it is active record specific (or at least it is database technology specific) and that was the reason to put it into rspec-rails. Do you recommend to use it for gem development (ActiveRecord is used), or do think something like database-cleaner is better in that case?

Comment: I think that if you can integrate the same functionality without using rspec-rails (because you are not actually using Rails), it would be better.

Comment: It also doesn't seem to really work even when adding rspec-rails. One gets `uninitialized constant Rails` error. And when then adding `require "rails"` the `undefined method` error of transactional fixtures shows up again. I will use database-cleaner now.